# Given a sequence of integers whose sum is 1, prove that exactly one of the cyclic shifts has all of its partial sums positive.

Tags: contest-math

[image: Question Statement]

I tried to understand the solution from the book for this question, but I am having hard time to understand it.

[image: A Solution]

How do we know that there exist two terms $x_{j}$ and $x_{j+1}$ such that $x_{j}\gt0$,$x_{j+1}\le0$ by taking indices modulo $k+1$?

Comment: do examples. What happens, exactly, when $n=2?$

Comment: @WillJagy When $n=2$, $x_{1}$ must be positive because all partial sums must be positive. But the sum of $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ must be $1$, so $x_{2}$ must be less than or equal to $0$. To be specific, $x_{2}$ is $0$ when $x_{1}$ is $1$, and $x_{2}$ is negative when $x_{1}$ is larger than $1$.

Comment: @WillJagy I understand it works for $n=2$ case, but I’m not sure how to generalize it to $n=k+1$ case.

Comment: You say you don't see the way they are arguing induction. So, now show the $n=3$ case by induction, your own way. I am trying to get across the idea that understanding may not happen all at once, while working on sub-problems should help  one understand. Anyway, try $n=3$

Comment: Given that you tagged this with contest-math, are you familiar with the "cars around the racetrack with enough fuel to complete a lap" problem? If yes, this is very similar to it, and ideas there should translate over. $\quad$ For an alternative approach, plot $(1, x_1), (2, x_1+x_2), \ldots, (n, x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_n)$. Find the minimum of these points. If there are multiple minima, then take the rightmost point. Claim: This is the unique index for which all of the partial sums are positive. Proof: (Obvious) From definition of minima and rightmost.